# Freestyle behind not affected object

Tags: freestyle, collections

I am new at blender an experimenting with some functions. When I use freestyle on a collection it is all working fine. But with the text object in the foreground (in an other collection) and "visibility" set to visible the lines are kind of cut off when hidden by the text object in the foreground.[image]

Is there a way to make the lines somehow continue behind the text object so it looks like this (just done in photoshop so you would understand;)?
[image]

Thanks a lot ;)